# Creating Multidimensional Key Value array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a datatable with following structure.

[image: Datatable structure]

I want to create one key-value multidimensional array. i.e

```
main_array = {
  user_id  =  {
    'name' : 'XYZ',
    'email' : 'xyz@com'
  }
```

The checkbox containing column is like  :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="3" data-name="xyz" data-email="xyz@com">
```

Script I created till now  :

```
 var rows_selected = [];
 var $i = 0;    
 $("input:checked", rows).each(function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
    if($.inArray($(this).val(),rows_selected) == -1 ){
         rows_selected.push($(this).val());
         rows_selected[$i][val] = [];
         rows_selected[$i][val].push({'name':$(this).attr('data-name'),'email':$(this).attr('data-email')});
    }
    $i++;
 });
```

But this script always throws an error :  Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

So is it possible to create a key-value pair in javascript which pushes user_id as a key and name, email array as its value into main result array ? Can we also splice that particular key using javascript?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You do not have an array - You have an **object**

Comment: ^^ ...the valid expression of which would use `:`, not `=`, after `user_id`.

Comment: @Weedoze so how to get desired output?

Comment: @ArthParikh You should create an object and assign the value instead of using push

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to relate to the structure you said you want, not least because the names are different. Is `rows_selected` supposed to be `main_array`? Why are you trying to add properties to strings? (The result of `val` is a string; you then try to add a property to the entry you just pushed as a string via assignment on the `rows_selected[$i][val] = [];` line.)

Comment: Depends on what you actually need. Do you need an object with key/value pairs (aka a hashmap) ? `{ "id1" : { "name" : "john", "email" : "john@google.com" }, "id2" : { "name" : "jane" , "email" : "jane@google.com" } }` Or do you want a real array? `[ { "id" : 1, "name" : "john", "email" : "john@google.com" }, { "id" : 2, "name" : "jane" , "email" : "jane@google.com" } ]` ?

Comment: @Shilly yes i want a real array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having to guess a bit here, but if your goal is to have an object with properties named by `$(this).val()` whose values are objects with `name` and `email` properties), then:

```
var rows_selected = [];
$("input:checked", rows).each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var entry = {};
    entry[$this.val()] = {
        name: $this.attr('data-name'),
        email: $this.attr('data-email')
    };
    rows_selected.push(entry);
});
```

I don't see any need for the `inArray` check (and couldn't understand what you're trying to do with it).

Example:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var rows_selected = [];
  $("input:checked"/*, rows*/).each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var entry = {};
      entry[$this.val()] = {
          name: $this.attr('data-name'),
          email: $this.attr('data-email')
      };
      rows_selected.push(entry);
  });
  console.log(rows_selected);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="one" data-name="name for one" data-email = "email for one">
    One
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="two" data-name="name for two" data-email = "email for two">
    Two
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="three" data-name="name for three" data-email = "email for three">
    Three
  </label>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if you don't need an array, just an object with the `$(this).val()` keys, it's simpler — both to build, and to consume later:

```
var rows_selected = {};
$("input:checked", rows).each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    rows_selected[$this.val()] = {
        name: $this.attr('data-name'),
        email: $this.attr('data-email')
    };
});
```

Example:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
var rows_selected = {};
$("input:checked"/*, rows*/).each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  rows_selected[$this.val()] = {
     name: $this.attr('data-name'),
     email: $this.attr('data-email')
    };
  });
  console.log(rows_selected);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="one" data-name="name for one" data-email = "email for one">
    One
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="two" data-name="name for two" data-email = "email for two">
    Two
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="three" data-name="name for three" data-email = "email for three">
    Three
  </label>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: inArray  I used to avoid duplicate entries of user_id on checkbox click event of select/deselect all. I tried your code but the output has $this.val() as undefined.

Comment: @ArthParikh: Then you're not quite doing the above, as `val` **never** returns `undefined` when there's an element in the jQuery object you call it on, as there definitely is with `$this.val()` (since `$this` is `$(this)`).

Comment: I am always getting the value as Object in my final array.

Comment: @ArthParikh: I don't know what you mean by that. If you're using the array version of the answer above, of course you are: We're putting objects in the array. But those objects have useful properties.

Comment: This my output :   Object {1: Object, 2: Object}.  Here i am not able to get value of id.

Comment: @ArthParikh: No, that's just a *rendering* of your output you're seeing somewhere. The two examples above work, see the console output shown for them in the snippets. You'll have to work with it more to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an array of objects, like follow:

```js
var rows_selected = [];
var $i = 0;
$("input:checked").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var attrs = {'name':$(this).attr('data-name'),'email':$(this).attr('data-email')};
    rows_selected[$i++] = attrs;
 });
console.log(rows_selected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="1" data-name="xyz" data-email="xyz@com" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="2" data-name="abc" data-email="abc@com" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="3" data-name="jjj" data-email="jjj@com" checked="checked">
```

If you use a multidimensional array, like:

```
rows_selected[$i][val] = [];
```

You could get an array with "empty" elements, due arrays in JavaScript are "ordered", see following example:

```js
var test = [];

test[0] = "zero";
test[4] = "four";

console.log(test);
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: No it didn't helped Bye.

Comment: You also had inverted:
         rows_selected.push(val);
         rows_selected[$i][val] = [];
         rows_selected[$i][val]

Before you create an array at index `val`, then you access to an unexisting record `rows_selected[$i]`.